# What does $\to$ mean in the following definition of a block cipher?

Tags: block-cipher, notation

In the following picture $\kappa$ is the key length and $n$ is the block size.

I understand that $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ means all possible combination of keys and $\{0,1\}^n$ means all possible combination of a plain-text block.

But I don't understand the overall equation, specially the meaning of the arrow $\to$. Can anyone explain it in brief? (note: I am very weak in mathematics)

> Let $E: \{0,1\}^\kappa \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a block cipher with a $\kappa$ bit key and an $n$-bit state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That definition is a standard definition which defines encryption as a [function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) $E$. That function takes two inputs, a $\kappa$ bit key and a $n$ bit message.  Hence it is defined over the [cartesian product](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) - denoted as $\times$ - over these two sets, i.e. all bitstring of length $\kappa$ and $n$ respectively. It maps - denoted as $\rightarrow$ -  to an $n$ bit output (the ciphertext).

Comment: O! yes... Functions! Cartesian Product! ...totally forgot what those are... its been over a decade since I last study on those!  Thanks DrLecter. But "cryptography" is getting hard right now since maths are involved.

Comment: I was wondering to know, who gave this standard definition and when? perhaps I can avoid going through mathematics and read the original constructor's writings of this definition, which might save some time. And hoping it would be easier to understand. Because, I believe the constructor might have explained it in his writings with simple examples ---its a guess.

Comment: @Giliweed That definition is very natural to formally model (block) ciphers. You will find a description in any textbook. For instance, take a look at the [respective chapter](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap7.pdf) of the handbook of applied cryptography (which is freely available online).